# Socket.io - How to send auth error to client?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using `socket.io` on server side and `socket.io-client` on client side.
I have the following custom authntication function:

```
io.use(function(socket, next){
    console.log("Query: ", socket.handshake.query);
    // return the result of next() to accept the connection.
    if (socket.handshake.query.foo == "bar") {
        return next();
    }
    // call next() with an Error if you need to reject the connection.
    next(new Error('Authentication error'));
});
```

If the authentication fails, I want the client to know that.
However, its not triggering the `connect_error` on my client side.

Is it not possible? If it is, what am I doing wrong? Do I need to do something more on the server or client side?

Comment: try writing document.write on `connect_failed` to client.

Comment: @SatishPatel are you sure? because the connection is not done yet, and the event in docs is `connect_error`

Comment: you can send `socket.emit("authError")` to the client and then terminate the connection.. or not ;)

Comment: @mk12ok, even thats not working.

Comment: It will work when you add `socket.on("authError", () => { some action} );` to the client's code

Comment: I dont want to create a custom event. If someone tries to connect to my server, they need to get the authentication error. They wont know they have to subscribe to `authError`

Comment: Also, this is during the handshake, BEFORE the client gets connected. I can only emit the message AFTER I let him connect.

Answer (score 2):

I just figure out what my problem was, I defined a middleware using the root manager (`io`):

```
const SocketIO = require('socket.io');
const io = SocketIO.listen(server.listener, options);

io.use((socket, next) => next(new Error('ERRRRROR')));
```

And on the client side, I was connecting to the `/devices` namespace:

```
manager = io.connect('http://192.168.33.34:7650/devices');
manager.on('error', (e) => console.log(e));
```

On every connection, the `error` callback was never executed until I tried to set the middleware to the defined namespace `/devices`:

```
const nspDevices = io.of('/devices');
nspDevices.use((socket, next) => next(new Error('ERRRRROR')));
```

Then the `error` callback was successfully executed client side.

I hope this helps you.